# Radio stream using just audio package?

Tags: flutter

I have used just audio package for all the urls with ending .mp3 data from apis but i want to stream radio url also can i use the same player for playing the acc format  urls from api or i need to add another package for the player.

Comment: Please, check the package pubdev website as it clearly specifies those functionalities https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The audio file was not playing because the url starts with http flutter by default does not support the http urls it only allows https urls so play them i have added the below code to the android manifest file:

<application
....
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
....
/>